# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused. Even after having configured /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to check if elasticsearch is properly working on Ubuntu 14.04. So for that, I am running following commands:

```
$ sudo service elasticsearch start
$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

Error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

I am attaching screenshot of my /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file here and also attaching my-application.log
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you see int he ES logs in `/var/log/elasticsearch/my-application.log`?

Comment: I've added the screenshot of a part of /var/log/elasticsearch/my-application.log

Comment: Let me know, if any other part of log file is neede

Comment: Ideally, it would be nice to see the full log file during start up.

Comment: Here you go, check out here.. https://codeshare.io/2BlKvx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is pretty evident from the log file

> org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [linux-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml

Simply add this to your `elasticsearch.yml` config file and restart the service

```
xpack.ml.enabled: false
```